# From sp_BlitzIndex I see "Table metadata not in memory" - What does this actually mean?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

[image: There is a note I don't quite understand]

Is this saying something about the statistics for the index (or table?). I see stats for the non-clustered index as well as the clustered. Does it mean something else?

This is from Brent Ozar's FirstRespondersKit, sp_BlitzIndex

Answer (score 1):

It means there is no data (and thus no metadata) in the SQL Server memory for the table in question which those reads and writes are measured for.

Here's the code snippet for that section of the proc:

```
        index_op_stats AS ISNULL(
            (
                REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30),CAST(total_singleton_lookup_count AS MONEY), 1),N'.00',N'') + N' singleton lookups; '
                + REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30),CAST(total_range_scan_count AS MONEY), 1),N'.00',N'') + N' scans/seeks; '
                + REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30),CAST(total_leaf_delete_count AS MONEY), 1),N'.00',N'') + N' deletes; '
                + REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30),CAST(total_leaf_update_count AS MONEY), 1),N'.00',N'') + N' updates; '
                + CASE WHEN ISNULL(total_forwarded_fetch_count,0) >0 THEN
                    REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30),CAST(total_forwarded_fetch_count AS MONEY), 1),N'.00',N'') + N' forward records fetched; '
                ELSE N'' END

                /* rows will only be in this dmv when data is in memory for the table */
            ), N'Table metadata not in memory'),
```

Comment: ok good to know. what do i actually "do" about this?  what SHOULD i do? or what wasn't done in the first place?

Comment: Nothing in particular. From the reads and writes, it's getting used. It just wasn't used recently.

Comment: And recently is subjective... something could have just cleared it out of memory like a DBCC operation, index rebuild, whatever...

Comment: cool - maybe this isnt even related to my problem them.  thats why i posted this. to get more insight. i have an SSIS insert to a table from a flatfile that seems to lock (i think) a table used by a webapp at the same time.  the import does WAY too long - when it normally doesn't.

Comment: I see. Personally I would bulk insert into a staging table if possible and then update / insert into your actual table. This is a common practice since you can also create indexes on your staging table, making your inserts / updates quicker (since you are joining).

Comment: thats what I was thinking.  adding a staging table could be the first step to help speed it up. and didnt even think about the index on staging.  so could have it create one (update it since it will already have it?) on the staging table.  I actually need to TRUNCATE the fact table each time. and thus the staging, so fully import the new data each time. and when you say bulkimport - you are referring to the tsql for that? i actually havent done that before. just have always used SSIS. should i instead? (prolly call it from ssis is ok? or direct tsql in agent job?)

Comment: SSIS would still be fine here. I am not a SSIS guru so I tend to just script everything I can.